# Error when converting datetime from UTC to Brasilia datetime in Power BI

Tags: datetime, powerbi

Expression.Error: Não conseguimos converter o valor #datetime(2024, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0) em tipo DateTimeZone.
Detalhes:
Value=28/03/2024 00:00:00
Type=[Type]

**I hope that in the date.times column I subtract a difference of 3 hours so that the data presented in the other columns is coherent. The data shows that at 10am UTC it is starting to have irradiance (sunrise), however in Brazil it should be around 7am which is correct.**

[image: Result before converting]

`let
// Definir os dados JSON
json = [
api_token = "cb8551da59dbdf91be8371df4a03dddb",
power_source = "solar",
id = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
variables = {"solar_irradiance_panel", "power"},
end_date = "20241231",
integration = "hourly"
],

```
// Converter o JSON em uma string JSON formatada
jsonString = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(json)),

// Definir a URL
url = "https://api.tempook.com/geracao/v1/forecast/multiforecast/range/integration",

// Obter os dados da API usando o método POST
response = Web.Contents(
    url,
    [
        Headers = [
            #"Content-Type"="application/json"
        ],
        Content = Text.ToBinary(jsonString),
        ManualStatusHandling={405}
    ]
),

// Converter a resposta JSON em uma tabela
jsonResponse = Json.Document(response),
#"Convertido para Tabela" = Record.ToTable(jsonResponse),
Value = Table.FromRecords(List.Transform(#"Convertido para Tabela"{0}[Value], each [id = [id], data = Table.FromColumns({[solar_irradiance_panel], [power], [times]}, {"solar_irradiance_panel", "power", "times"})])),
#"data Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Value, "data", {"solar_irradiance_panel", "power", "times"}, {"data.solar_irradiance_panel", "data.power", "data.times"}),
#"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"data Expandido",{{"data.times", type datetime}}),

// Converter a coluna "data.times" para o fuso horário de Brasília (-3 horas)
ConverterParaBrasilia = Table.TransformColumns(#"Tipo Alterado", {"data.times", each DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(_, -3, "UTC")}),
// Converter a coluna "data.times" para o fuso horário de Brasília (-3 horas)
#"data times" = ConverterParaBrasilia{0}[data.times]
```

in
#"data times"`